# How do i compile opencv_ffmpeg.dll file using mingw on windows 10 64 bit?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I have tried many different methods for compiling opencv_ffmpeg.dll but they all fail. Can somebody tell me which mingw (32bit or 64bit) version and msys or msys2 version to use and how to configure them properly for the task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been successful in acheiving this? If positive, could you elaborate the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

For Solve **"CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1043  (file): ... "** Errors In Cmake
Follow This Steps:

---

You have to download *(Manually)* your **Three** required **files/dlls**

- `opencv_ffmpeg.dll`
- `opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll`
- `ffmpeg_version.cmake`

---

Each file has its own **MD5 HASH** code.

So for that, Go to :

`C:\`**`[PATH_TO_YOUR_OPENCV]`**`\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.cmake`

Open it, And You Get *Informaions About All Things*.

Now, Find This Line :

**`FFMPEG_BINARIES_COMMIT xxx...`**

> Note **`xxx...`** it's an `MD5 HASH Code`, You should find only **`FFMPEG_BINARIES_COMMIT`**

And Get **MD5 Key** For Your Version, For Example for me, I got this result :

`FFMPEG_BINARIES_COMMIT 2a19d0006415955c79431116e4634f04d5eb5a74`

So my **MD5 Key** is : `2a19d0006415955c79431116e4634f04d5eb5a74` **ok !**

---

Finally, Put This **MD5 Key** In The Link Below,

And Replace **[MD5_CODE]** With  Your MD5  Key Code ^^

Also Replace the name of *Each File/dlls* of Required List in **[FILE]**.

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/`**`[MD5_CODE]`**`/ffmpeg/`**`[FILE]`**

---

Start Download Each File With Link

**opencv_ffmpeg.dll:**

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/2a19d0006415955c79431116e4634f04d5eb5a74/ffmpeg/opencv_ffmpeg.dll`

**opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll:**
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/2a19d0006415955c79431116e4634f04d5eb5a74/ffmpeg/opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll`

**ffmpeg_version.cmake:**
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/2a19d0006415955c79431116e4634f04d5eb5a74/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_version.cmake`

---

When you finish

- Go to:
  `C:\`**`[PATH_TO_YOUR_OPENCV]`**`\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\downloads`

Each of *3 file/dlls* Have a **MD5 HASH** code, ok!

- `opencv_ffmpeg.dll`
- `opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll`
- `ffmpeg_version.cmake`

So you have to know it,

> Because the name of each folder must be an MD5 code.

Add Three Folders :

- First Folder Name : `MD5 HASH code of opencv_ffmpeg.dll`

  - put into : **opencv_ffmpeg.dll**
- Second Folder Name : `MD5 HASH code of opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll`

  - put into : **opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll**
- Third Folder Name: `MD5 HASH code of ffmpeg_version.cmake`

  - put into : **ffmpeg_version.cmake**

That's All :)

Answer (score 0):

be sure you are using 32 Bit softwares
be sure you have internet connection while using CMAKE for configuration.
be sure to **activate your windows**.