# Use FFMPEG in OpenCV without internet connection

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, qt-creator

I am creating a project in c++ with QtCreator (5.14.1, MingGW compiler) and trying to use OpenCv (3.4.16) to read video files. I have tried many files of standard formats and codecs (H.264, yuv420, .mov etc). However, no matter what I try, VideoCapture() always silently fails. It doesn’t crash or show any error code, instead isOpened() is just always false.

I think the cause is that I am building opencv (via this tutorial https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows) without internet connection (I cannot have internet connection on this machine, so please do not ask me to) and therefore it can’t download the FFMPEG libraries during this process. I have been looking everywhere for information about how to download the FFMPEG libraries for opencv directly but I haven’t had any luck.

Can someone please explain what libraries I need to download and how opencv goes about looking for them? because at the moment I don’t know what I need, nor where to put them, and I cant find any information on the topic.

Or, can someone explain why calling VideoCapture(“video.mov”, cv::CAP_ANY) doesn’t have any effect? (despite being able to play the video easily in VLC, MediaPlayer etc).

Code:
`

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(“C://video.mov”);
    //VideoCapture cap(“C:/video.mov”);
    //VideoCapture cap(“C:\video.mov”);
    //VideoCapture cap(“C:\video.mov”);

    if (!cap.isOpened()){
        cout << "Error opening video stream or file"<< endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

`

I have tried downloading some ffmpeg DLLs and the EXEs and adding them to the PATH, no success. I have also tried downloading the shared GPL of ffmpeg (that comes with the libs and include) and added them my .pro file but no change in VideoCapture behavior.

I have also tried moving the opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll (found in opencv/build/bin) to my executable directory but that didn't fix anything.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Windows installer of FFMPEG and transferring and running that? Or does it need a special additional install?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean sorry. I have downloaded and used FFMPEG for a while with no problem. I just downloaded the Zip, extracted and added to PATH. If you download the shared GPL of FFMPEG you also get the .libs, .dlls and include headers, but as I said in the post I couldn't figure out how to use them with opencv.

I would also be interested to know if anyone can tell me any other reason VideoCapture would quietly always return false, the FFMPEG issue is just my hunch.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem; it seems weird that this would not give you more details about why it failed, but I have no experience with FFMPEG. Have you been able to run this with on another computer, or are you not able to? Sounds like a lot of things can go wrong.

Comment: Tell me about it, its insanely frustrating it provides no feedback. Im pretty certain its because it cant find the FFMPEG Dlls though. I just need to know exactly what ones I need to download and how I setup opencv to use them when the online download failed.

Comment: How did you get your OpenCV sources on the disconnected machine?

Comment: What did the tests of the individual components yield?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/need-to-build-opencv-with-ffmpeg-cant-have-cmake-download-files-no-internet-connection/10978/5

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this guys answer,

[How do i compile opencv_ffmpeg.dll file using mingw on windows 10 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943015/how-do-i-compile-opencv-ffmpeg-dll-file-using-mingw-on-windows-10-64-bit)

Just note that some of the directories are a little different now. You don't need to put them in a folder named after the hash, or in a 'download' subdirectory, and you need to copy all of them to opencv-build/3rd party/ffmpeg/. I also put them in opencv/source/3rd party/ffmpeg, but not sure if I needed to do that. Finally you need to go into the ffmpeg.cmake file and set 'status' to TRUE when the download fails (or just remove the download part altogether), this lets it call ffmpeg_version.cmake and set things up.